# how do I transform input value using regexp using php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I'm trying to build a regex solution to transform and input in a form into a consistent format of xxxx-xxxx where x is a numeric character from 0-9
The common input errors we come across and what they should be transformed to are :-

xxx-xxxxx to xxxx-xxxx

xx-xxx-xxx to xxxx-xxxx

xxxxxxxx to xxxx-xxxx

xxxx xxxx to xxxx-xxxx

xxx xxxx to xxxx-xxxx

xx xx xxx to xxxx-xxxx

x= numeric character 0-9

Is their simple regex match and transform that would allow us to achieve this?

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: I'd suggest that you want the first 4 numerals, a hyphen, then the last 4 numerals, but I'm not sure its that simple, as in come cases you seem to be generating a numeral when none existed in the input.

Comment: Soooo.... You lost interest or what?

Answer (score 0):

Strips non-digits then adds a `-` after the first four digits.  This also takes care of `xxxx.xxxx`, `xxxx/xxxx` and whatever else:

```
$input = preg_replace(array('/[^0-9]/','/^(\d{4})/'), array('','$1-'), $input);
```

You should check after to make sure the length is what you need, in this case `9`:

```
if(strlen($input) != 9) { /* ERROR */ }
```

Comment: I'm being a stickler, but how do you handle this case in the example given--xxx xxxx to xxxx-xxxx

Comment: I stated it but the code is: `if(strlen($input) != 9) { //ERROR }`

Comment: ;-) I interpreted that you were checking your results, but I see now you are checking the input. The OP's examples do show several cases that would fail the input check. Case of poor examples or a more complex problem?

Comment: Well, that's kind of like a date input and the user doesn't enter the year.  Do you add a default year or reject the input?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$str = '123 - 4 5 6 7-8';

$res = strtr($str, [' '=>'', '-'=>'']);
$res = substr($res, 0, 4) . '-' . substr($res, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript  http://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/kuujybzm/

```js
var str = 'My ID: 3431 5443';
var pattern = /(\b[\d\s-]{5,8}\d+\b)/;
var str = str.replace(pattern,'$1').replace(/[-\s]/g,'');
str = (str.length<8)?'0'+str:str;  // if xxxx-xxx is fine, then don't need
str = str.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{1,4})/,' $1-$2');

alert(str);
```